# Bazel docker container image not copying file

Tags: docker, kubernetes, bazel, bazel-rules

I'm trying to emulate [theRUN step](https://github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-health-probe) you would fine in a docker file shown below in the [Bazel docker container image rule](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_docker/blob/master/docs/container.md#container_image) but since the `container_image` rule does not have a copy function I'm trying to use what is available.

```
RUN GRPC_HEALTH_PROBE_VERSION=v0.3.1 && \
    wget -qO/bin/grpc_health_probe https://github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-health-probe/releases/download/${GRPC_HEALTH_PROBE_VERSION}/grpc_health_probe-linux-amd64 && \
    chmod +x /bin/grpc_health_probe
```

```
  go_image(
      name = "go_auth_image",
      embed = [":go-auth_lib"],
      visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
  )

  container_image(
      name = "go_auth_api",
      visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
      base = ":go_auth_image",
      ports = ["5001", "5002"],
      files = ["grpc_health_probe-linux-amd64"],
      symlinks = {
          "grpc_health_prob-linux-amd64": "/bin/grpc_health_probe",
      },
      cmd = [
          "apk add --no-cache git",
          "chmod +x /bin/grpc_health_probe",
      ],
  )
```

note: `file_map` does not seem to be a parameter for `container_image`

When I deploy this image to k8s the the image runs fine but the when describing the pod the liveness probe (described below) fails.

```yaml
          livenessProbe:
            exec:
              command: ["/bin/grpc_health_probe", "-addr=:5002"]
            initialDelaySeconds: 5
            periodSeconds: 30
            timeoutSeconds: 2
            successThreshold: 1
            failureThreshold: 3
```

```
  Warning  Unhealthy  6m42s                  kubelet            Liveness probe errored: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to exec in container: failed to start exec "b6c89b7ec907e572f80be59e8d4b5cad6535a3479d67a3563a09e0d1d2f7ca03": OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:370: starting container process caused: exec: "/bin/grpc_health_probe": stat /bin/grpc_health_probe: no such file or directory: unknown
```

What is the correct way to setup this probe with Bazel (I've confirmed this works with a Dockerfile setup)

Comment: https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_docker/issues/1943

Answer (score 1):

[container_run_and_commit](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_docker/blob/master/docker/util/README.md#container_run_and_commit) is the closest equivalent to `RUN`. Something like this is the direct equivalent:

```py
load("@io_bazel_rules_docker//docker/util:run.bzl", "container_run_and_commit")

GRPC_HEALTH_PROBE_VERSION = "v0.3.1"

container_run_and_commit(
    name = "install_stuff",
    image = ":go_auth_image.tar",
    commands = [
        "wget -qO/bin/grpc_health_probe https://github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-health-probe/releases/download/%s/grpc_health_probe-linux-amd64" % GRPC_HEALTH_PROBE_VERSION,
        "chmod +x /bin/grpc_health_probe",
    ],
)


container_image(
    name = "go_auth_api",
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
    base = ":install_stuff",
    ... # everything else you're doing with container_image
)
```

It runs the commands a builds a new image, and then uses `container_image` to add things to the result.

However, doing more of the build with bazel will make better use of bazel's cache and be more reproducible. I think that's what you're doing with the `grpc_health_probe-linux-amd64` source file. That approach looks something like this:

```py
load("@io_bazel_rules_docker//docker/util:run.bzl", "container_run_and_commit")

container_image(
    name = "add_stuff",
    base = ":go_auth_image",
    ports = ["5001", "5002"],
    files = ["grpc_health_probe-linux-amd64"],
    symlinks = {
        "grpc_health_prob-linux-amd64": "/bin/grpc_health_probe",
    },
)

container_run_and_commit(
    name = "go_auth_api",
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
    image = ":add_stuff.tar",
    commands = [
        "apk add --no-cache git",
        "chmod +x /bin/grpc_health_probe",
    ],
)
```

That uses `container_image` to add things first, and then runs the commands afterwards.

Also, instead of running `chmod +x`, you can use [pkg_tar](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_pkg/blob/main/pkg/docs/reference.md#pkg_tar) to package the file+symlink (it has a `symlinks` attribute just like `container_image`), and then set `mode = 0755`. `container_image.tars` will take the tar file and add it to the image. In general, `pkg_tar` gives a lot of flexibility for building up files, and `container_image` takes a subset of its functionality directly for simple use cases.

[container_image.cmd](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_docker/blob/master/docs/container.md#container_image) is the equivalent of `CMD` in a Dockerfile. It's just setting the information when the container is used, not doing anything while building it. I don't think you want to use it at all for this.

Comment: For the "filename manifest.json not found error": see my edit to the answer, you have to put `.tar` at the end of the `image` value. For the dbus error with docker: I think that's related to WSL and/or your docker setup, I see you asked in a separate question which is the correct place to ask.

Comment: Yeah, snap install of docker won't work so you have to use windows docker desktop install. Another problem though is that the run and commit rule runs the go binary which panics because it can't connect to some services

Comment: Working around the issues with running, the original error persists where it can't find /bin/grpc_health_probe and I think that is because the base go_image doesn't have bash

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Brian-Silverman help I was able to triage all my issues and landed with this solution.

```py
  go_image(
      name = "go_auth_image",
      embed = [":go-auth_lib"],
      visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
  )

  GRPC_HEALTH_PROBE_VERSION = "v0.4.5"


  container_run_and_commit_layer(
      name = "health_probe",
      image = "@grpc_health_image//image",
      commands = [
          "apk add --no-cache git",
          "wget -qO/bin/grpc_health_probe https://github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-health-probe/releases/download/%s/grpc_health_probe-linux-amd64" % GRPC_HEALTH_PROBE_VERSION,
          "chmod +x /bin/grpc_health_probe",
      ],
  )

  container_image(
      name = "go_auth_api",
      base = ":go_auth_image",
      layers = [":health_probe",],
      visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
      ports = ["5001"],
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

I've responded to your github issue, but posting the answer here as well for visibility: I would accomplish this in Bazel by making a TAR which contains the `grpc_health_probe` binary in the location I would like and add that in the `tars` section of a `container_image` rule. I try to avoid the `RUN`-like rules, because they introduce a dependency on the docker toolchain and they are not guaranteed to be hermetic/reproducible. There's an open issue about this here: https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_docker/issues/1961.

You can declare the binary in question as a dependency in your `WORKSPACE` (or a macro invoked by your `WORKSPACE`) like so:

```
load("@bazel_tools//tools/build_defs/repo:http.bzl", "http_file")
GRPC_HEALTH_PROBE_VERSION = "v0.4.5"
GRPC_HEALTH_PROBE_SHA256 = "8699c46352d752d8f533cae72728b0e65663f399fc28fb9cd854b14ad5f85f44"
http_file(
    name = "grpc_health_probe_linux_amd64",
    executable = True,  # Here is your `chmod +x` from the `container_run_and_commit`
    sha256 = GRPC_HEALTH_PROBE_SHA256,
    downloaded_file_path = "grpc_health_probe",  # This is necessary to remove `-linux-amd64` from the end of the file name.
    urls = ["https://github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-health-probe/releases/download/{}/grpc_health_probe-linux-amd64".format(GRPC_HEALTH_PROBE_VERSION)],
)
```

Having done that, and included the `rules_docker` toolchain configuration, you can then add this binary to a container image with a build file that looks like the following:

```
load("@rules_pkg//:pkg.bzl", "pkg_tar")
load("@io_bazel_rules_docker//container:container.bzl", "container_image")

# This rule creates a TAR file containing the executable file
# /bin/grpc_health_probe.
pkg_tar(
    name = "health_probe_linux_amd64",
    srcs = ["@grpc_health_probe_linux_amd64//file"],
    package_dir = "/bin",  # specifying the path of the file
)

# Here, we add that health probe to our base image. In this case
# I've used the ubuntu image for a minimal example.
container_image(
    name = "health_probe_image",
    base = "YOUR_BASE_IMAGE_HERE",
    tars = [":health_probe_linux_amd64"],
)
```

Github reply: https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_docker/issues/1943#issuecomment-998400122