# Docker install via Snap on WSL internal error, cannot create transient scope: DBus error "org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnixProcessIdUnknown"

Tags: docker, bazel, bazel-rules, snap

Running a Bazel rule `container_run_and_commit` that throws the following error.

```
internal error, please report: running "docker" failed: cannot create transient scope: DBus error "org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnixProcessIdUnknown": [Process with ID 8 does not exist.]
```

More details documented here [Bazel docker container image not copying file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69715902/bazel-docker-container-image-not-copying-file)

Not sure how this can be corrected.

Comment: Does the number after ID change if you try several times, or is it always 8?

Comment: always 8. I ended up uninstalling snap docker and replaced with windows docker desktop and it is working better.

Comment: That sounds like the right solution.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to not use the snap install of docker and instead the Docker desktop with WSL2 install on.

Note that in WSL the `~/.docker/config.json` will show creds as `desktop.exe`. This works fine with the docker cli but better to change `desktop.exe` to `""` and `docker login` to store credentials natively if other tools are using docker. In my case that is Bazel.